Telegram теряет название и исполнителя песни в inline режиме
Код на питоне, aiogram
Имеется телеграм бот, в котором через инлайн режим можно искать треки в саундклауде и отправлять.
До того как мы отправили трек в чат мы можем его прослушать (что многие и делают, надо же удостоверится что всё правильно).
Теперь важно:
В самом поиске всё отображается адекватно;
Если мы сразу отправляем трек, то всё нормально.
Но если мы послушаем трек, а затем его отправим, то песня отправляется, но теряет название и исполнителя, пробовал добавлять описание и какого-то черта оно всегда работает.
Как понимаю название трека берется из ссылки на загрузку, которую я получаю с саунда.
Сам код создания массива инлайн ответа:
result.append(InlineQueryResultAudio(
                        id = hashlib.md5((f"{iname}+{iduration}+{iartist}").encode()).hexdigest(),
                        audio_url = iurl,
                        title = iname,
                        performer = iartist,
                        audio_duration = iduration
                    ))

Ну и соответственно вопрос у меня возникает как вообще другие боты работать при таких условиях работать могут, но надеюсь я чего то не понял/не нашёл и есть метод решения.
Надо, чтоб и послушать можно и отправить возможно!

По такому фрагменту кода сложно понять, что там у вас происходит.
